# Resize of Iframe dynamically depending on the content of the Iframe of the Iframe's src URL

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

I want to resize the height of Iframe dynamically on the content of the IFrame's src URL and the this src is coming through Webservice method.

please help any one..thanks

Comment: You mean like setting the width and height based on the url?

Comment: ya.i have gone through a lots of article but it's not giving a fruitful result and in some cases it giving security violation thread.

Comment: Can't you simply set the style of the iframe: `style="width: 100px; height: 200px;"` where the width and height values will be calculated on the server side based on the value of the source of the iframe?

Comment: i can set styles on the same way but inside iframe i don't want scrolling.

Comment: If you don't want scrolling set the height of the iframe to a sufficiently large value.

Comment: really i don't want that to set height sufficiently rather the height will grow or shrink according to the Src's content.

Answer (score 1):

When the website is from the same domain, you can use this code, which expands the frame as much as possible:

```
var frame = document.getElementById("name_of_iframe");
var contentframe = document.frames["name_of_iframe"];
contentframe = (contentframe.contentDocument||contentframe.windowWindow.document).body;
frame.style.height = contentframe.scrollsetHeight + "px";
frame.style.width = contentframe.scrollWidth + "px";
```

Comment: here i am looking for cross domain.

Comment: That's not possible, due the severe cross-origin restrictions.