# dynamically resize iframe based on its contents

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I would like to know of a quick javascript solution to make an iframe shrink/grow in size based upon the contents inside of it, so that the scrollbar is not needed.

The frame source is changed based upon input from the user, and I would like the iframe to adjust its size based upon that.

the iframe code I have is:

```
<iframe id="edit_add_configuration" src="<?php echo site_url();?>">
        browser does not support this
</iframe>
```

Comment: Is the iframe and outer page on the same domain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize of Iframe dynamically depending on the content of the Iframe of the Iframe's src URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441443/resize-of-iframe-dynamically-depending-on-the-content-of-the-iframe-of-the-ifram)

Answer (score 2):

Get the height and width.

```
var height = document.getElementById("edit_add_configuration").contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
var width = document.getElementById("edit_add_configuration").contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
```

Resize the iframe.

```
document.getElementById("edit_add_configuration").style.height=height+"px";
document.getElementById("edit_add_configuration").style.width=width+"px";
```